# First League of Legends champions

Tags: league-of-legends

I was curious about who were the first champions when League of Legends was released. Anyone knows? It seems like it's nowhere on the Internet =/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

League of Legends launched on October 27, 2009.

These are the original champions available at launch:

1. Alistar
2. Amumu
3. Anivia
4. Annie
5. Ashe
6. Blitzcrank
7. Cho'Gath
8. Corki
9. Dr. Mundo
10. Evelynn
11. Fiddlesticks
12. Gangplank
13. Heimerdinger
14. Janna
15. Jax
16. Karthus
17. Kassadin
18. Katarina
19. Kayle
20. Malphite
21. Master Yi
22. Morgana
23. Nasus
24. Nunu
25. Rammus
26. Ryze
27. Shaco
28. Singed
29. Sion
30. Sivir
31. Soraka
32. Taric
33. Teemo
34. Tristana
35. Tryndamere
36. Twisted Fate
37. Twitch
38. Veigar
39. Warwick
40. Zilean

Comment: A complete list of all champions and their release dates can be found on the [league of legends wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions).

Answer (score 2):

There are the original 43, but according to Guinsoo in an old post somewhere on the forums, Singed was the first champion they started to develop.

> Twisted Fate was one of the first six characters designed, along with Singed, Annie, Sivir, Sion and Lee Sin

Quoted from [the Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twisted_Fate_the_Card_Master/SkinsTrivia#Trivia)

Comment: Lee sin was released in May 2011. That's 1 and a half year after launch.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lolking.net/champions/

Sort by released dates. As you can see the first batch of champions have been released in 2/21/2009.

- 17 champions 2/21/2009
- 2 champions 4/18/2009
- 3 champions 5/1/2009
- 1 champion 6/12/2009
- 2 champions 6/26/2009
- 2 champions 7/10/2009
- 1 champion 7/24/2009
- 1 champion 8/7/2009
- 2 champions 8/19/2009
- 4 champions 9/2/2009
- 2 champions 9/19/2009
- 1 champion 10/1/2009
- 2 champions 10/10/2009
- Offical Launch 10/27/2009

A lot of champions have been added from the alpha phase until launch as you can see.

Comment: why downvote?????

Comment: Your video doesn't exist, maybe that's why

Comment: my video existed on the day of downvotes

Comment: well atleast now you don't

Comment: could have been because you didn't say the champ names like the top comment did lolz

Comment: but i answered the question correctly. the question is first champions, not first champions at launch time. plus the op couldnt find any tools, so i gave him the best tool about this on the internet

Comment: that is true, meh , maybe the person who asked question just didn't like your answer ( which is dumb ) or didn't see the quality of it